# access inner element from json object

Tags: jquery, json

I want to acess innermost value in json array.This json data i get using ajax call.

Below is my json data get from server :

```
{
"meta": {
    "limit": 20,
    "next": null,
    "offset": 0,
    "previous": null,
    "total_count": 7
},
"objects": [
    {
        "id": 2,
        "other": "{}",
        "name": "gmail"
    },
    {
        "id": 3,
        "other": "{'userinfo': [{ 'user1': { 'user_name':'nancy','address': [], 'outfields': ['login', 'url','type','id']}},{ 'createissue': { 'type':'post','infields': ['owner','repo','title','body'], 'outfields': []}}",
        "name": "yahoo"
    }
]
```

}

Now here i want the value of  user_name using jquery. how to get it? please someone help 
me.

i tried like this :-

```
   user=rows.objects[i].other.userinfo[0];
```

but its not work

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that `rows.objects[i].other` isn't parsed, it's still JSON.

You should do

```
var obj = JSON.parse(rows.objects[i].other);
var info = obj.userinfo ? obj.userinfo[0] : undefined;
```

But if you're the one generating the JSON, you might want to fix the generation : you shouldn't embed JSON in JSON.

EDIT : `rows.objects[i].other` is't even valid JSON : it's incomplete and has `'` instead of `"`.

Comment: Yes, but this value isn't an object but a JSON string. That's why you need to parse again.

Comment: @dystry Ok,but it gives an error as:- "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property '0' of undefined" when i try to print value of info on console.

Comment: In fact, there is another problem that I see now : your inner "JSON" is in fact invalid. Where do you get that strange "JSON" from ?

Comment: @Snehal The external JSON, yes, not the internal one that is in `other`.

Comment: i made changes but still can't access value 'nancy' of user_name

Comment: Where do your strange "JSON" comes from ? Can you fix the generation ?

Comment: yup.. i fixed it and get it correctly.i use the code you provide but still can't access value. when object is empty shows, info=undefined but when it contains data it shows " info= [object object]"